# What is best approach? NSDictionary Or Custom Object based Data strcuture?

Tags: objective-c, data-structures

I was talking to several developers which approach is best in objective C according to latest trends?

For example: if i am populating data from server in json form, which approach should i use?

I have seen my friends populating data into json objects in past as well as fewer of them in **NSdictiory,NSMututable Dictionary**, what apple recommends data structure wise?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Following trends? What is that nonsense about? We write stable code, we don't follow trends. Apple doesn't recommend anything. I know what to do to write stable code.

Answer (score 2):

I personally greatly prefer custom objects (or Structs for Swift) because it lets me more easily tell what properties the objects have. If you are just passing around dictionaries it makes it much harder (in my opinion) to remember what object you have, what keys it has, and maybe what nested objects it has too. Whereas if you have named classes (again, these ought to be Structs in Swift), then you (and the compiler) can easily know what properties they have. Plus you can easily create instance methods for your objects.

And if you don't want the pain of parsing them yourself there are frameworks that will manage parsing the server response into objects (e.g. RestKit https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit).

If you consider example code from Apple as a "recommendation" from Apple, you can see the way they make a data model in their "Start Developing iOS Apps" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson6.html. Yes the example is for Swift but most concepts are comparable.

Apple also has "Cocoa Core Competencies" (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ModelObject.html) where they define a modal object as "typically a subclass of NSObject or...a subclass of NSManagedObject."